# reset the form on back button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have searched on the web but couldn't find any solution.
When I click on the 'Submit' button on 'samplepage.php', I redirect the page to the 'newpage.php' page. I would like to reset 'samplepage.php' form values when user clicks on back button of the browser. Right now it keeps all the textbox values, radio button and checkbox selection. Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Here is my redirect php code.

```
header ("location:newpage.php);
```

Comment: What web browser(s) are you doing the testing in?

Comment: you could use the form's `reset()` method in the `onload` event...

Comment: I have to support all the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The pageshow event is sent to a Window when the browser displays the window's document due to navigation. This includes: Navigating to the page from another page in the same window or tab

**Example pageshow event and reset form on browser back button**

```
<script>
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
    $('#yourformid').trigger("reset");

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't watch the browser's back button with server-side code.

You need Javascript and jQuery with a little knowledge in the 'popstate' and 'pushstate' arena

Comment: jQuery is not necessary for this. :/

Comment: it's not 'REQUIRED', but with the OP's obvious understanding of client side code, wouldn't you recommend a library, and maybe a polyfill?

Comment: Perhaps, instead of handing people a 90k library for a 4 line solution we should consider that people are capable of thought; if they're here to be handed code without the intention of understanding how it works they are in the wrong place to begin with.

Comment: If what you say is true than if they can use a library, that means they're aware of the weight... And you can't tell me you've NEVER used code you didn't fully grasp... If you claim to, you're full of it.

Comment: I work as a developer for a credit card processing company... if I don't understand how it works and it breaks bad things happen. So, no, I won't implement things I don't understand.

Comment: yeah in a production environment... lol of course not... I used to work for Chase Bank for the company that handled all their ACH sooo... woo hoo! And I said 'used' not 'implemented' don't patronize me.

Comment: Well then, I'm glad we're on the same page that we shouldn't use code that we don't understand. :]

Comment: yes we agree, you should never publish code to a public facing website or web service or portal of any kind that you don't full grasp. When you're developing though, it can be one of the best ways to learn.

Comment: "if they're here to be handed code without the intention of understanding how it works they are in the wrong place to begin with". intention. Yes, I'm glad we agree.

Comment: that last one didn't make sense... might wanna just give it a rest because that has nothing to do with what I said.

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to the browser.

You can empty your inputs at last moment (before submitting) and put the values in some hidden fields...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to clear it on page load if you really want to do this. If you have more than a few controls you'll want to loop through the form to clear it. Assuming they're *all*  items...

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
{
    elems[i].value = '';
}
```

It gets all input controls, loops through them all and sets their values to blank.
You can extend this to work for radio buttons/checkboxes by setting .checked depending on their type.

Just my two cents on the issue though, it's a bad idea to clear the form. There's a reason browsers retain the state they do.

For example, if validation failed on server side and I had to go back and re enter everything I would not be happy. :(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot die()

```
header ("location:newpage.php");
die();
```

You can also try resetting your $_POST, $_GET and $_SESSION vars

```
unset($_POST,$_SESSION, $_GET);
header ("location:newpage.php);
die();
```

**Update**: just read you're trying to unset 
on history back, I didn't realize that in my 
above code...

You're going have to write some markup code to clear the 
variables associated with the input fields and selection 
lists of the form.

Whatever.js

```
function clearForm(formIdent) 
{ 
  var form, elements, i, elm; 
  form = document.getElementById 
    ? document.getElementById(formIdent) 
    : document.forms[formIdent]; 

    if (document.getElementsByTagName)
    {
        elements = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for( i=0, elm; elm=elements.item(i++); )
        {
            if (elm.getAttribute('type') == "text")
            {
                elm.value = '';
            }
        }
        elements = form.getElementsByTagName('select');
        for( i=0, elm; elm=elements.item(i++); )
        {
            elm.options.selectedIndex=0;
        }
    }

    // Actually looking through more elements here
    // but the result is the same.
    else
    {
        elements = form.elements;
        for( i=0, elm; elm=elements[i++]; )
        {
            if (elm.type == "text")
            {
                elm.value ='';
            }
        }
    }
}

function addEvent(elm, strEvent, fnHandler)
{
    return ( elm.addEventListener
    ? elm.addEventListener( strEvent, fnHandler, false)
    : elm.attachEvent( 'on'+strEvent, fnHandler)
    );
}
```

In the Form Div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[
    var el = document.createElement("input");
    el.setAttribute("id", "clearButton");
    el.setAttribute("type", "button");
    el.setAttribute("value", "Clear");
    document.getElementById("FormDiv").appendChild(el);
    addEvent(el, 'click', function(){ clearForm('form_name');} );
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use the HTML event 'onunload' to do the same thing the posters before have suggested. From your perspective it probably does not matter WHEN you fire the event.

Answer (score -1):

Clear the values on page load.

```
<input type="text" id="ClearIt" value=""/>
```

Place this in the opening body tag:

```
onload="document.getElementById('ClearIt').value=''"
```